# Fire jquery script in fancybox iframe

Tags: php, jquery, iframe, fancybox, phpmailer

I'm quite new to js, whole day tryin' to accomplish this: I have file.html which I load in a Fancybox iframe. It contains some text (which goes OK) and a form (where trouble begins). I need the submitted data to be sent via email.

I also try to apply a mask to phone input field, but it seems than jquery just won't fire inside iframe. It works just fine on index.html page (the form and mask).

Here's the HTML of the file that loads in Fancybox iframe:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="callback.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="maskedinput.min.js"></script>

<span id="wb_uid1">Some text here</span>

 <form class="form form-deal" name="special-price" id="Form1">
       <input type="hidden" name="formid" value="form1">
       <input type="text" id="Editbox2" class="phone" name="phone" value="" placeholder="Phone number">
       <input type="text" id="Editbox1" name="name" value="" placeholder="Your name">
       <select name="Combobox1" size="1" id="Combobox1">
          <option >option 1</option>
          <option >option 2</option>
       </select>
       <input type="submit" class="btn" id="Button1" name="Submit" value="Submit">
                  
 </form>
```

The contents of the "callback.js":

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="phone"]').keypress(function(e) {
        if (!(e.which==8 || e.which==43 || e.which==0 ||(e.which>47 && e.which<58))) return false;
    });

    $("form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('.form-callback .btn').click(function () {
        if ($(this).parent('form').find('input[name="name"]').val().length>0 && $(this).parent('form').find('input[name="phone"]').val().length>0 )
            AjaxFormRequest($(this).parent('form').attr('id'),'mail_callback.php');
    });
    $('.form-deal .btn').click(function () {
        if ($(this).parent('form').find('input[name="name"]').val().length>0 &&
            $(this).parent('form').find('input[name="phone"]').val().length>9)
            AjaxFormRequest($(this).parent('form').attr('id'),'mail_order.php');
    });

    function AjaxFormRequest(form_id, url) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            data: jQuery("#" + form_id).serialize(),
            success: function (response) { 
                $('#'+form_id+' .message').text("Sucess!");
     $('#'+form_id+' *:not(".message")').fadeOut(500);
                $('.overlay, .popup').delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
            },
            error: function (response) { 
                $('#'+form_id+' .message').text("Error");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And the mail_order.php

```html
<?php
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: order <order@mysite.com>\r\n";
$subject = "New order";
$message = "Name: " .$_POST['name']."<br/> Email: " .$_POST['email']."<br/> Phone: " .$_POST['phone']."<br/> Options: "
    .$_POST['quantity']."<br/> ZIP: " .$_POST['index']."<br/> Adress: " .$_POST['address']."<br/> Delivery: " .$_POST['delivery_type']."<br/>";
if(@mail("mymail@gmail.com", $subject, $message,  $headers))
    ;
else
    echo "Mail error!";
?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help on this!

Comment: Have you tried replacing your <br/> with \r\n in your mail_order.php ?